# Как правильно вычислить последовательность для вывода?

Tags: php

Всем привет

как вывести вот в такой структуре,

```
<div>
   <div class="double items">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
   </div>
   <div>3</div>
<div>
<div>
   <div class="double items">
      <div>4</div>
      <div>5</div>
   </div>
   <div>6</div>
<div>
<div>
   <div class="double items">
      <div>7</div>
      <div>8</div>
   </div>
   <div>9</div>
<div>
```

$idx начинается с 1

```
{if $idx == 1 ||  $idx % 4 == 1}
    <div class="ascents-section">
{/if}
    {if $idx % 3 != 1}
         <div class="ascents-section__item ascents-double">
    {/if}
        <div class="ascents-double__item" title="{$id | resource: 'pagetitle'}">
              <div class="ascents-section__item-photo" id="photo-effect">
                <picture>
                  <source media="(min-width: 1440px)" srcset="{$id | resource:'image'}">
                  <img class="effectImg" src="{$id | resource:'image'}" alt="{$id | resource: 'pagetitle'}">
                </picture>
              </div>
              <div class="ascents-section__item-info">
                <h2 class="for-heading">{$id | resource: 'pagetitle'}</h2>
                <p class="subtitle">Легкий</p>
                <a href="{$_modx->makeUrl($id)}" title="{$id | resource: 'pagetitle'}" class="button button-program">Перейти</a>
              </div>
            </div>
    {if $idx % 3 == 1}
        </div>
    {/if}
    {if $idx % 3 == 1}
        <div class="ascents-section__item" title="{$id | resource: 'pagetitle'}">
            <div class="ascents-section__item-photo" id="photo-effect">
              <picture>
                <source media="(min-width: 1440px)" srcset="{$id | resource:'image'}">
                <img class="effectImg" src="{$id | resource:'image'}" alt="{$id | resource: 'pagetitle'}">
              </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="ascents-section__item-info">
              <h2 class="for-heading">{$id | resource: 'pagetitle'}</h2>
              <p class="subtitle">Тяжелый</p>
              <a href="{$_modx->makeUrl($id)}" title="{$id | resource: 'pagetitle'}" class="button button-program">Перейти</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/if}
{if $idx % 3 == 1}
    </div>
{/if}
```

Comment: казалось бы если исходный массив разбить на тройки, то задача станет куда проще. не так ли?

Answer (score 0):

Абстрактный пример, как можно "построить" нужную Вам структуру.

Сперва массив разбивается (исп. [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php)) на подмассивы с 3-х эл-тов, и уже каждый из них "обёртывается" div'ами

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

foreach (array_chunk($array, 3) as $items) {
    echo '<div><div class="double items">';
    foreach ($items as $idx => $value) {
        if ($idx === 2) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo "<div>$value</div>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, при отсутствии шаблонизаторов лучше построение верстки для одного элемента завернуть в функцию, и прямо вывести `<div class="double"><?= f($items[0]) ?> <?= f($items[1] ?></div><?= f($items[2]) ?>` а не колдовство с циклами, индексами и условным выводом, в которое в каждый раз придется втыкать

Comment: @teran потому это и абстрактный пример.. Я бы вообще весь код в одну функцию вынес и её вызывал бы где надо, а без цикла каждый эл-т выводить это сильно, да.